How can I trigger run of a GitHub Actions workflow created in runtime by some other workflow?
I have workflow, "creator.yml" which uses a script to create another worlflow, "new.yml". Now I want to trigger the run of "new.yml" automatically. Is is possible to do so in GitHub actions?
I tried on: workflow_dispatch, but it did not work.
name: 'My Workflow'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      parameter:
        description: My Parameter
  pull_request: -- Add this here
...

Trying this way, I keep on getting error: could not create workflow dispatch event: HTTP 422: Workflow does not have 'workflow_dispatch' trigger

Did you try triggering the new workflow using the Github API "create dispatch event endpoint"?
